# Mongoosejs Virtual populate does not retrieve foregin collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, models

This is the Answer Collection.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var answerSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    questionId:String,
    username:String,
    answered:Boolean
});


answerSchema.virtual('quest', {
ref: 'Question',
localField: 'questionId',
foreignField: '_id'
},{ toObject : {virtuals:true} }, { toJSON: { virtuals:true } });
```

and below is the query that I am using to try and populate from "Question" model based on id. But I get back only values from the "Answer" collection, even though there is data based on the ID in the foregin collection. What am I doing wrong ? EDIT: I am using Mongoose version "^4.6.7"

```
Answer.findOne({questionId:"58497379b0094008fe202b62"}).populate('quest').exec(function(error, vals) {
console.log(vals) }); // vals does not have the foregin collection related fields.
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a `_id = "58497379b0094008fe202b62"` in Question model? Try doing the query without condition as `Answer.find({}).populate('quest').exec(function(error, vals) { console.log(vals); });`

Comment: Yes, it exists as "_id: 58497379b0094008fe202b62" in the Question Model and as questionId: '58497379b0094008fe202b62' in the Answer Model. When I queried as you suggested the Answer model brings three values, I also queried the Question model and it brings in the record.  But the Virtual record, in my case vals.quest is undefined.